# Встреча участников сообщества Stack Overflow на русском в Киеве

Tags: обсуждение, встречи-сообщества

Читал на Meta о сходках участников в Москве и Санкт-Петербурге, однако не нашел ни одного упоминания о подобных встречах в Киеве, хотя часто вижу ребят на форуме из Украины.

Может быть организуем неофициальную встречу в Киеве, что скажете? Пообщаемся, обменяемся опытом, приобретем новые знакомства... Если тема приобретет достаточное внимание, обсудим время и я сделаю форму регистрации.

Comment: @Elena а о чем обычно разговаривает преимущественно мужское сообщество. О работе, о машинах (о компах), о том на каком сайте жену искать лучше, ну и так далее).

Comment: @Elena точно не дизайн) Думаю даже, что вряд ли разговор коснется SO. Скорее всего просто обменяемся опытом и приобретем новые знакомства.

Comment: @Elena, договорились же: участник - это он. Да, феминистки негодуют :)

Comment: С хорошими людьми всегда есть о чём побеседовать.

Comment: Интересно, а сколько тут киевлян? И - просто чтоб не было недоразумений, если такая сходка состоится - хоть я и местный :), скажу откровенно - не моё, я не пойду. Надеюсь, без обид. Просто не в моем характере - мне куда легче общаться вот так, с клавиатурой :)

Comment: В Киев ехать далеко, так что сомневаюсь, что приеду. Но было бы здорово, если бы такая встреча состоялась =)

Comment: Ну и где форма регистрации? Люди готовы уже. Кстати, на **Украине** не побьют **русское** сообщество?

Comment: @Other что за стереотипы? Меньше читайте СМИ. Неадекватных людей хватает везде.

Comment: Ну у меня лично была стычка на эту тему, когда я был в Киеве. И это печально - благодаря СМИ, стереотипы превращаются в реальность.

Comment: Щупленькие кодеры в очках? Только если собрать T-800, залить чистейшего ассемблера и с собой взять. P. S. Где всякие лазертаги? :)

Comment: @Other опять стереотипное мышление) Я к примеру больше 100 кг вешу)

Comment: Ну тогда весело ноги гопов от Вас отскакивать будут :)

Comment: @Other а вы случайно в Киеве не начинали разговоры о том какие украинцы фашисты и бандеровцы? И сообщество не `русское`, а  `русскоязычное`, разница есть.

Comment: @FoggyFinder, да ладно, гопников везде хватает,а повод приколупаться всегда найдётся

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick полностью согласен. Мне не понравилось как были расставлены акценты в том комментарии, поэтому решил уточнить действительную причину конфликта.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54719/discussion-between-other-and-foggy-finder).

Comment: Чёт я не понял, встреча всё таки будет или нет?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick инициатора кто-то додумался забанить)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Проведение встречи в Киеве – это прекрасная инициатива! Спасибо!

Как мне кажется, есть несколько важных момент, которые следует учесть.

1. Если вы считаете, что компания Stack Overflow как–либо может помочь вам в организации встречи, пожалуйста, напишите об этом мне ([контакты в моей учетной записи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile)) или свяжитесь с командой развития сообществ через [форму обратной связи](/contact). К примеру, некоторые из пришедших участников, были бы рады небольшим сувенирам, например, наклейкам, которые мы будем рады отправить вам совершенно бесплатно.
2. Помните о праве на деперсонализацию участников. Далеко не все участники хотят связывать свою активность в Интернете с активностью в реальной жизни. Это право каждого. *Внимательно подходите к сбору личных данных для встречи*. Из нашего опыта организации встреч, единственное обязательное поле для ввода личных данных – это ссылка на учетную запись на одном из сайтов Stack Overflow. Для всего остального: (1) следует назначить как не обязательные к заполнению поля; (2) следует явно указать, как будет использоваться собранная информация. Например, организуя встречу в Санкт–Петербурге, мы просили указать номер телефона, для того чтобы была возможность связать, в случае если кто–то потеряется. Но (!) поле не было обязательным и мы оставляли телефон организатора. Сами собранные данные более нигде и никогда кроме как для конкретной встречи не использовались!
3. Организуя встречу самостоятельно, пожалуйста, **в явном виде укажите, что организатор именно вы, участник сообщества, и именно вы, как организатор, собираете личные данные**. *Это крайне важно!* Многие участники могут не понимать, что откликаясь они передают свои личные данные именно вам, а не компании. Пожалуйста, укажите в явном виде, зачем вам эти данные – это повысит доверие к вам, а как результат, вероятность откликов. *Не запрашивайте личные данные, которые на самом деле не нужны для встречи.* **Ни в коем случае не используйте собранные данные ни для каких целей, кроме как для организации мероприятия.**
4. Если вам нужна какая–либо консультация, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь связаться с кем–либо из команды развития сообществ для получения дополнительной помощи.

Answer (score 10):

Я поддерживаю идею встречи в любом городе. Но хочу, чтобы ее организовывал участник, который:

1. Поддерживает и соблюдает правила сообщества.
   Не делает систематических попыток нарушить эти правила, не использует «лазейки» в механике сайта, чтобы привлекать внимание к своим ответам.
2. Прочитал, понял и принял условия о конфиденциальности информации, описанные в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4858/181472).

Пока что я не вижу такого организатора встречи в Киеве.
Давайте его найдём или договоримся, что в Киев приедет Николас.

Comment: Тут великолепно бы подошёл пруфлинк. Ну общественное дело, как бы.

Comment: @Other, на что именно?

Comment: Ну на примеры нарушений/предупреждений, справки из местного вытрезвителя, etc.

Comment: Думаете, такой участник будет склонять других к нарушению правил сообщества? Мне кажется, если бы был кто-то другой (более подходящий по Вашему мнению) готов к организации подобной встречи, он бы уже нашёлся. А если других нет? Настаивать на отмене подобного мероприятия или что?

Comment: downvote - Не думаю, что это место для обсуждения @Vadizar -а и то, какие правила он нарушал(-ет).

Comment: @FoggyFinder, хочет быть организатором - пусть оголит онлайн-душу :)

Comment: @Nick встреча планируется как неофициальная. Да и вообще не пойму, какое отношение к встрече может иметь мой прошлый бан? За то, что я назвал некоторых людей неадекватными, мне теперь нельзя встречаться с участниками сообщества?

Comment: @Vadizar не могу говорить за недовольных (сам не из них), и сам в Киев в ближайшее время не собираюсь, но предполагаю, что от вас добиваются более явного/очевидного указания на то, что встреча **неофициальная** и организована не SO (п. 3 в ответе Николаса). Вот.

Comment: @D-side, а почему бы не сделать официальную, с блекджеком и наклейками? Местный представитель согласен помочь чем может. Загвоздка только одна - официальным представителем не берут этого чувака из-за... судимости.

Comment: @Other полагаю, что официальными встречами считаются лишь те, которые организованы сотрудниками SO **лично**. Другое дело, что толку от такой официальности не очень много, поскольку сайты SO в большой степени состоят из сообщества и в "доверенной стороне" для таких встреч нет большой необходимости, как для "встреч по интересам". В крайнем случае, можно организовать и возглавить своё подсообщество, самостоятельно отпечатать наклейки, и т. п. :)

Comment: @D-side, ну если официальное лицо выберет наместника в регионе встречи, где официальных лиц физически нет - почему бы и нет? Однако, я думаю компания не захочет нести ответственность за каких-то чуваков, которым один сотрудник, потрепав по голове, разрешил от их имени что-то сделать, а сделано криворуко (собрались не там (могила Ленина?), напились и надепоширили, может кто погиб на встрече, etc). Выход один: только **полуофициально** собраться - как бы клуб по интересом, но с участием компании (стикеры всякие, если повезёт - вечнозелёные на помещение с напитками и техникой для выступления).

Comment: @D-side *К примеру, некоторые из пришедших участников, были бы рады небольшим сувенирам, например, наклейкам, которые мы будем рады отправить вам совершенно бесплатно.* Наклейки заслать не проблема.

Comment: @Nofate это не имеет никакого отношения к "официальности" встречи, на мой взгляд. Николас хорошо расписал в своём ответе, о чём я говорю.

Answer (score 6):

Помоему идея отличная, собраться можно и на свежем воздухе) Правда как это будет выглядеть? Типа клуба анонимных оверфлоуверов)

Comment: "Привет! Я Harry, и я кодоголик..." :)

Comment: Ахаха, где-то так)

Answer (score 3):

И всёже когда и где, и по сколько? А темы, темы какие? Нужно раскручивать это движение в Украине и желательно в разных городах.

Comment: Да тут некоторая драма происходит, организатор было сделал форму, но её убрали из вопроса модераторы (с концами, даже из ревизий выжгли). Подозреваю, что из-за несоблюдения требований, высказанных нашим менеджером сообщества, Николасом ([см. п. 3 ответа](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4858/181100)). Так что пока что ничего не назначено. Вы ничего не пропустили и вряд ли пропустите, т. к. пост о встрече отметят меткой [meta-tag:важное], и если вы часто бываете на SO, быстро заметите объявление.

Comment: А теперь организатор [и вовсе забанен](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36101332#36101332). Так что нужно другое инициативное лицо. И подозреваю, что готовность увидеть на встрече ныне забаненного :)

Comment: @D-side я вернулся!

Comment: @Vadizar добро пожаловать!

Comment: @Vadizar что-то вы недолго продержались :(