# Наиболее удобные города для встреч

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, встречи-сообщества

Приветствую.
Предлагаю решить сообществом где наиболее удобно провести встречи SO на русском.

Вдруг в одном городе наберутся десяток-другой желающих?
Тогда пусть собираются, Николас поддерживает инициативы и [пообещал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4858/207618) помочь, если надо.
Хоть и без блекджека и официальных представителей, но уже хорошо.

Правила:
Город - число приемлющих это место как встречу (не обязательно Ваш, просто наиболее удобный, может вообще село, если место глухое).
Кто желает - инкрементируйте число или добавьте свой город.

Пример:

```
Санкт-Петербург - 39
Агаповка - 5
```

Comment: лучше разбить города на ответы и по плюсам посмотреть :)

Comment: @Grundy поговорите ещё, и встреча будет в Мюнхене :]

Comment: @D-side, так говоришь, как будто это что-то плохое ;-)

Comment: Хотел было сделать "один город - одно сообщение". И голосовать сразу плюсами. Но тогда ожидается много сообщений, сложно искать. В одном ответе проще.

Comment: а чего сложно искать? ставишь сортировку по голосам - и максимальный наверху

Comment: @Grundy, а если хочешь найти наиболее удобный для себя город?

Comment: Чёй-то  за откат-то?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Что необходимо учесть для организации встречи сообщества?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4891/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```js
var cities = document.getElementsByTagName('cities')[0];
var list = cities.innerHTML.trim().split('\n') .map(function(c){return c.trim().split(/\s+-\s+/); });
byNames = function() {cities.innerHTML = list.sort(function (a, b) {return a[0].localeCompare(b[0]); }).map(function(a){return a.join(' - ');}).join('<br/>\n'); };
byVotes = function() {cities.innerHTML = list.sort(function (a, b) {return (b[1]- a[1])||a[0].localeCompare(b[0]); }).map(function(a) { return a.join(' - ');}).join('<br/>\n'); };
byNames();
```

```html
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body>
<button onclick="byNames()">По алфавиту</button>
<button onclick="byVotes()">По голосам</button>
<hr/>
<cities>
Астана - 1  
Бердск - 1  
Волгоград - 1  
Воронеж - 2  
Днепр - 1  
Екатеринбург - 1  
Иркутск - 1  
Калининград - 0  
Киев - 2  
Краснодар - 1  
Красноярск - 1  
Липецк - 1  
Москва - 7  
Мюнхен - 2  
Новосибирск - 2  
Омск - 1  
Оренбург - 1  
Самара - 1  
Санкт-Петербург - 6  
Томск - 1  
Улан-Удэ - 1  
Харьков - 1  
</cities>
</body></html>
```

Comment: что значат все эти цифры?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, цифры после городов? В вопросе же написано: "Город - число приемлющих это место как встречу".

Comment: Что-то Калининград до сих пор нулевой. Может его выпилить к чертям?

Comment: @alexolut, вставил для примера. Хотите - выпиливайте, хотя он никому не мешает ИМХО.

Comment: Тот, кто голосовал за Мюнхен, реально представляет, как там организовать такую встречу?

Comment: @RomanPodymov, Да, он там живёт :) Если бы народ набрался, в таверне зал с пивом, сосисками и грудастыми разносчицами могли бы арендовать.

Comment: @Other Это ни о чём не говорит. Надо же будет найти конференц-зал или кафе, договориться обо всём, разместить рекламу. Я могу приехать на встречу сообщества, если она будет в Мюнхене, но сможет ли её кто-то организовать.

Comment: @RomanPodymov, Какую рекламу? Кафе вряд ли очень сложно арендовать. Проблема что там от силы пару-тройку человек может быть. А это проще - списались, встретились и всё.

Comment: @Other Может тогда проще создать вопрос для встречи в Мюнхене? Или даже не там, а в городе, куда будет удобно добираться в пределах ЕС.

Comment: @RomanPodymov, Зачем? Напишите тут город, можно хоть в Майами, главное что если у кого-то будет желание, можно было бы встретится (кто какой город добавил можно посмотреть в ревизиях).

Comment: Default City лидирует, Default City 2 отстает :)